# Can't pass some tests for freecodecamp pomodoro clock + getting better at react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The timer *appears* to work fine, but I can't pass all the tests in the given test suite. The failed tests are not consistent either, sometimes 3 fail, sometimes 4. Before this post, the ones that failed are 13-15 in the 'Timer' section (12 also fails sometimes). All these tests are related to when the countdown reaches 0. Please point out where I'm going wrong.

Link: https://codepen.io/importhuman/pen/eYdGpKN

Part of the code I think might be responsible:

```
timerStart(){
const {currSession, currBreak, timerMin, timerSec} = this.state;
let duration = timerMin*60*1000 + timerSec*1000;
let nextTimerMin = currBreak <10 ? "0" + currBreak : currBreak;

if (this.state.active) {
  var x = setInterval(()=> {
      if (this.state.active) {
          duration = duration-250;
          var min = Math.floor(duration/60000);
          var sec = Math.floor((duration%60000)/1000);
          min = (min < 10 && min >= 0) ? "0" + min : min;
          sec = (sec < 10 && sec >= 0) ? "0" + sec : sec;
          if (duration>0){this.setState({timerMin: min, timerSec: sec});};
         
        if (min == "00" && sec == "00"){
          this.playSound();
        }
          if (duration<=0){
              clearInterval(x);
              this.setState({timerMin: nextTimerMin, timerSec: "00", activeSession: "Break"}, ()=>{ this.breakStart()});
          }
      } else {
          clearInterval(x);
      } 
  }, 250);
} 
}
```

Also, I think I have the wrong idea of how to use React. I seem to only think of organising content in components, nothing more. How can I be more effective? Perhaps it's linked to my limited knowledge of JavaScript as well, so what would you say are the must-knows of JS?

Thanks!

Comment: Once the tests have completed, clicking the "Tests xx/29" button shows the tests, which failed, and gives descriptions of each test. This should help with debugging.

Comment: @Ouroborus yeah I did, made some changes as well but doesn't work :/